# Excel: how to dinamically change sheet reference in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have sheet A which is a big table with data referring to January and sheet B which extrapolate data from sheet A and in cell formulas there is the link to that sheet. Now I'd like to duplicate sheet A and sheet B naming them: A2 and B2 and formulas in B2 refer automatically to A2 data. is it possible or I have to change manually the reference to the new sheet?

thanks

Comment: If this is a one time thing the use Find/Replace to change the sheet names.  If not, look into Indirect() as it will allow you to set the sheet name in a cell on the page and then refer to that in your formulas.  Thus when you copy you only need to change the one cell and all the formula will refer to the new sheet.

Comment: Have you tried simply select the sheets A and B together as a group (using mouse and shift key), then right click the selected registers and choose Move or Copy, then (move to end) and [x] Create a copy?

Comment: @AxelRichter error message: "You cannot copy or move a group of sheets that contain a table."

Comment: @kiwi1342: You are right. I hadn't read that there is a table. Then this will not work.

Comment: @ScottCraner your answer is correct but the indirect cell reference doesn't change when copying the formula. Each row has the formula that goes for example: A1:C1. Using INDIRECT the A1:C1 range is kept through each line and not automatically upadated.

Comment: Post a new question, please include the formula you are trying and what you want to make dynamic.

Comment: @ScottCraner ok done. thanks